# Text based rpg index out of range error

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple text based game.

```
while True:
    choice = raw_input('>>: ')
    aa = choice.split()

    if aa[0] == 'examine':
        if aa[1] == 'key':
            print "It's a key alright."
        else:
            print "I can't examine that!"
    else:
        print "I don't know how to do that."
```

I keep getting list index out of range when i type something other than "examine key"
I know WHY it does this but how do i fix it?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not seeing the error if you type something like "examine door" or "examine purple potion" or "look key", only when you type "examine" with nothing else, correct?

Comment: just a heads up you may want to look at creating a base "object" type class that has methods to use examine etc ... that will be much much better in the longrun and avoid one massive if/else statement

Answer (score 2):

Check the length before indexing.

```
if len(aa) > 1:
```

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: `if aa` isn't sufficient . . . the code fails because the inner conditional doesn't handle the case when there aren't enough arguments.

Comment: @ernie: in that case, `if len(aa) > 1` will also fail. `if len(aa) > N` must be used instead, where `N` is the number of expected arguments

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I'm pretty sure you mean if `len(aa) >= N` ; len is not 0 indexed . . .

Comment: @ernie: You're right. Actaully, `len(aa) >= N` would be equivalent and easier to understand at first read

Comment: Hah, looks like I made the edit same time you were responding . . . I actually started with >=N, but then changed it as I was thinking something else